# Could not serialize object: IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm following [this guide](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/how-to-install-pyspark-on-mac/) to install spark on my laptop. I have installed `python@3.11` and `spark 3.3.2`. I tried running Jupyter notebook from terminal and I tried to run the code below

```
data = [("Java", "20000"), ("Python", "100000"), ("Scala", "3000")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df.show()
```

I got the error below: `PicklingError: Could not serialize object: IndexError: tuple index out of range` I tried to downgrade python to 3.10 because only Spark 3.4.0 can use Python 3.11, at the time of writing not yet released at IT worked fine from terminal but when rerunning Jupyter notebook the python version was every time upgraded to 3.11.

I'm facing the error for 2 days and i was not able to resolve it alone, don't hesitate to tell me if something was not clear.

Commands:

```
python --version  
-> 3.11.2
pyspark --version 
--> 3.3.2
```

Thank you
[image: error]

Comment: Can you add more information about your environment , you have posted a very generic setup

Comment: @Vaebhav yess sure ! Done ! i updated my post . Have you an idea please?

Comment: Does the notebook by chance install any packages before running the spark code?